# Exporting a log from iPhone application

Tags: iphone, export, file-format

One of the features in my application is a log where a user can add log entries. I want to make it possible to for the user to export this data. However I do not know which format I should use for this. The data looks like this:

A date, distance, duration, maximum four category names. What I want is to make it possible to send it on mail or open it with dropbox using the URL scheme if the user has dropbox.

I have read about CSV format but I don't know if that is a good file format? My main concern is that the user do not have to have a fixed number of categories (could be between 1-4 categories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the columns of data to be exported will be dynamic in total, it will depend on what the user selects - and there's nothing wrong with this.

I think .csv is fine for this purpose as well - but you need to ask yourself... what will the user be doing with the data? You could either offer multiple file export formats or whatever is the best-for-purpose format, depending on what your average user will do with it.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply. CSV is a perfect fit for the data I am exporting, so the dynamic column count doesn't matter?

Comment: The method that you write which'll collate the required data or fetch it from arrays/dictionaries or whatever your structure is, will feed off whatever they contain. It should be no problem at all for you to interpret their contents and create your csv file dynamically. Try it and keep us posted with how you get on :)

Comment: Okey, thank you. I will fetch the data from my sqlite database and I will read more about the CSV format first. I will update my answer when I have got it to work:)

Answer (score 2):

CSV (comma separated values) is simple (and adds very little overhead - the commas), but not terribly flexible. This is good for importing to MSFT Excel, for instance.

You should consider using XML (the same underlying format used for plists) which is a very flexible (future proof should you wish to add additional columns in the future) and well supported format.